# Workspace not getting mapped correctly

Tags: tfs

I have my workspace mapped like the following:

```
<Team Project>/<directory 1>/<directory 2>
```

When I run my build, however, I get the following error.

"No matching items found in `<Team Project>/<directory 1>` in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access them."

This happens during the Create Label stage. I am pretty sure I have about every right in our TFS 2010 server.

This happened after I got errors about workspaces already being mapped and subsequently deleted the offending workspaces.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about a TFS build or a local desktop build in Visual Studio?

Comment: This is regarding TFS builds.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the the correct permissions to create a label, but does the account where the build runs with (the service account of the build) have the rights?

Comment: Yes, Network Service runs the build on the machine, and I have given Network Service every right in the appropriate folder.

Answer (score 0):

check the command line of the 'label' command. There is a 'path' there, which is the path you want to label. Are you sure it is the correct path? I had the same issue, and I noticed that the path is incorrect.

In addition, Make sure you have permission to that folder and make sure the folder is not empty and contains at least one single file, since you cannot checkout an empty folder in TFS version control. See [here](http://www.aymanzaza.com/2012/02/20/no-matching-items-found-in-version-control-in-your-workspace-or-you-do-not-have-permission-to-access-them/).

Answer (score 0):

Try without a specific change set.